# Why does ZSH crash when autocorrecting PYTHONPATH=$(PWD) test to ...pwd...?

Tags: zsh

When I enter

```
PYTHONPATH=$(PWD) test
```

into my ZSH it asks me if I want PWD to be autocorrected to pwd. If I don't, it works as expected (does not find PWD). But if I do, my zsh constantly crashes with

```
double free or corruption (out)
Achtung: Das Programm „/bin/zsh“ ist abgestürzt.
```

Is this somehow my fault? Or is this a bug in ZSH? If so, where to report it?

Comment: You should post your OS and zsh version. I have no problem with (Arch) Linux and zsh-5.8-252-g17ee9c5. Use `print $ZSH_VERSION` to get the version.